# How does the speed of convergence of these formulae for calculating PI compare with the best algorithms?

Tags: power-series, pi

I came across some series many years ago for calculating PI.
I found that the first member of that series has been known for a long time
in the math world.

It is the set of series defined by:

$$ \pi^k=T\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^k}$$

where $[T,k] = [6,2]$, for the well known one.

I have some value pairs for $k$ and $T$ that give rise to other series some of
which converge maybe hundreds of times faster than for the above.

For the sake of time, I give the fastest converging member of these series as
the one that has $[T,k] = [18243225/2 , 14]$.

For more information about the other series and their $[T,k]$ values, please visit
 http://gbenro-myinventions.blogspot.com.ng/

How does the case where $[T,k] = [18243225/2 , 14]$ compare with the best algorithms for computing $\pi$ available?

My simple java program on the blog tells me that for just 12 terms, it converges to PI = 3.141592653589793 which is the accuracy available for `Math.PI` in the Java programming language.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can continue beyond $k=14$, e.g. $[T,k]=[1531329465290625/174611,20]$.

Comment: Wow...so what's up with the numbers...is there anything in maths that describes them?

Comment: Read about [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). $\pi^{2n}=\frac{(2n)!\zeta(2n)}{2^{n-1}|B_{2n}|}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative error for $\pi^k$ after summing $n$ terms is $\approx n^{-k}$. Computing the $k$th root then does little change (the relative error becomes $\frac 1kn^{-k}$). Hence the number of correct digits is essentially $k\log_{10}n$. For any fixed $k$, this does not grow very well if we compare it to what [the Borweins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein's_algorithm) managed (in the linked Wikipedia article you will find a description of an algorith with nonic convergence, i.e., $\sim 9^n$ correct digits after $n$ steps).

Comment: So for my case here about how many correct digits do you think I will have as compared to Borwrin's?

Comment: Well, let's say you need 12 steps to obtain 15 digits and for the sake of the argument assume that the nonic algorithm has only found 4 digits after 12 steps (which is not the case, it is much better). Then making 13 or 14 steps instead gains you at most one additional digit, whereas they have $\approx 9\cdot 4=36$ and $\approx 9\cdot 36>300$ digits after these two additional steps.

Comment: That is deadly!

Comment: Okay thanks..I wouldnt mind it if you had a look at some other stuff on my blog at the link I shared and analyze their uniqueness for me..please. Like the polygon formula. We could communicate anyhow you choose.

Comment: I hope you will do this please as I have much personal research that I have done and I really need a brilliant mind like yours to evaluate them and tell me if there is anything unique about them... We can talk in the comments section of the blog, if you please.